# MVC Validation Message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

On my view (aspx)

```
Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName")
```

is giving a return of

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Even though

```
ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.Values
```

doesn't have an entry for FirstName in it.

If I call

```
Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Nothing is returned.

What is going on? Where should I look for these values?

This is on the initial load of my view, so there shouldn't be any validation mesages showing. **How do I stop this unwanted message showing?**. If I submit the page, then `ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.Values` is populated how I would expect. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Hey, just a stupid doubt i had ... You have added the related validation Annotations on the Model property i.e. in your case FirstName ?

Comment: model is annotated properly, it seems to be coming down to the ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled web.config settings.

Comment: Probably you are quite on it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats correct functionality. The validation message has a class of `class="field-validation-valid"` the important bit is the **Valid** in this. If you invalidate the form you'll see the span will change to something like:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Destination.DestinationText">
<span class="" for="Destination_DestinationText" generated="true">The DestinationText field is required.</span>
</span>
```

notice the `class="field-validation-error"`.

Comment: Is this new functionality in MVC4? The same page on an MVC3 branch doesn't display these.

Comment: No, it's in MVC3. It's part of the unobtrusive javascript validation

Comment: My web.config on the mvc4 branch has different settings for UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled and ClientValidationEnabled which is why it isn't happening on the MVC3 version.

Answer (score 0):

These data attributes are used to perform client side validation using jQuery. When you add an MVC validation attribute like `Required` or `Range(0,2)` the attributes are added automatically. The attributes being on your field doesn't make the field invalid. For an invalid state, the css class `field-validation-valid` class is removed and the css class `field-validation-error` is applied. To prevent the data attributes being generated, you can disable JavaScript which obviously has a knock on effect. I would leave as is and be safe in the knowledge that everything is fine :)